# Using SCREEN_STATE_OFF properly

Tags: java, sony-smartwatch

I'm trying to use `SCREEN_STATE_OFF`. Based on the documentation I should set this screen state + in registration do this:

```
public boolean supportsLowPowerMode() {
    return true;
}
```

Having done that, it seems my application behaves strangely to users. When they start my control, it immediately disappears (but still seems to be running as it keeps sending some intents). Based on the documentation I'd expect they'll see a 4 colored version of screen with no backlight? I do only have an emulator, and the problem cannot be simulated there.

I'm setting `SCREEN_STATE_OFF` in the `onResume` method of the control, if that could be a problem.

Any advice how to properly set `SCREEN_STATE_OFF` and still show the app to users

Comment: Please tag this with the appropriate language - I'm assuming Java.

Comment: Did this, but I doubt this is useful for anybody interested in Java. This is 100% specific to Sony SmartWatch and only users interested in this topic can benefit from this post.

Comment: It is still always a good idea to tag the question with the language in question. It helps frame the question for answers (which you want to be in the right language!) and sets up the correct syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you doing this on a Sony SmartWatch 2?  This won't work on SW1.
2. Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve?  Setting SCREEN_STATE_OFF is different from enabling low power mode.  By turning on low power mode, you are telling the SW2 to allow your app to keep running in monochrome mode when the watch goes to sleep.  Sending SCREEN_STATE_OFF from your app's code is a way to manually start low power mode while your app is running.  Otherwise, the app will automatically enter low power mode when the display times out.
3. What are you doing in your layout when the watch is in full color mode?  Some colors cannot be shown in low power mode so that could be why the display is blank.
4. Take a look at the HelloActiveLowPower sample code in the /samples folder of the Sony Add-on SDK v3.0 for an example of how to use active low power mode.

Comment: 1) SW2 2) I'm doing this in order to keep accelerometer data coming for long time. If I'm right this is the only way to achieve that as automated screen dim would stop the sensor? 3) The layout for testing is super simple - white text on a black background. 4) Will check it out.